# Can I download an image using any function of Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

Can I download an image using any function of Selenium. Which will be similar to right click on the image and then click on "Save image as".  I have done it using build and class function and robot class. But I want something more effective.

Comment: There is no Selenium API which allows you download anything, however, you can send the keyevents to do the actions you are doing manually. and if Firefox is configured to download automatically (without saving any dialog) your file will be downloaded.

Comment: Can we use inetget command in AutoIt for this? can you please tell me how to do in firefox?

Comment: why you need to use AutoIt?

Comment: because we can download using "Inetget" command and it is autoIT command thats why i thought of that

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

With Java you can do it fairly easily, this should help using the java ImageIO class.

```
URL imageURL = null;

//locate image, xpath, css etc
 WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.XPath("picture"));

//get images source
 String elementsrc = element.getAttribute("src");

try {
        //generate url
        imageURL = new URL(elementsrc);

        //read url and retrieve image
        BufferedImage saveImage = ImageIO.read(imageURL);

        //download image to your workspace where the project is, save picture as picture.png (can be changed)
        ImageIO.write(saveImage, "png", new File("picture.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I am getting syntax error. Can you please guide me for using this

Comment: Hello, sir. I am new to both Selenium and Java. Still I unable to download the image. In the above code i have only replaced " WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.XPath("picture"));" with my image element . What other changes do I need to make so that it works

Comment: Below is the error I am getting

Starting ChromeDriver 2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed) on port 25290
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
 at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(Unknown Source)
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getWriter(Unknown Source)
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)
 at DownloadLabel.main(DownloadLabel.java:81)

Comment: are you able to send your test code, and the webpage html for the image